# SQL code for showing difference between two records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question about a SQL statement. And I hope I am able to explain it the right way so you can understand it.

I have a table where with articlecode, description, retailprice and sellingprice. Now I have to show only the record where retail price and selling price have a difference between them of €150.

So I started to think I could I do it? (Yes I am new to SQL)so:

```
SELECT articlecode, description, retailprice, sellingprice  
FROM article 
WHERE retailprice (and here I do not know).
```

Hopefully you can help me.

Comment: Hint:  `retailprice - sellingprice = 150`

Comment: use this condition  WHERE retailprice - sellingprice = 150

Comment: If the below post worked for you then you can approve the answer so that other would prefer it :)

Answer (score 0):

It will be like this:

```
SELECT articlecode, description, retailprice, sellingprice  
FROM article 
WHERE sellingprice-retailprice = 150
```